# Inserting value from one table to another in MySql with javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

I'm trying to get 3 values to insert from the table, 'parents' to the table, 'children' in MySql. One of the values, entitled "code" inserts perfectly. However, I can't get the other two, "email" and "website" to insert. When I add them to the javascript code, it just inserts "code" 3 times. Can someone help me please? Here's the code that inserts just the 'code' field from parents to children:

```
$("a#reply").one("click", function() {
        var comCode = $(this).attr("name");
        var parent = $(this).parent();

        parent.append("<br /><form id='reply-form-toggle' action='' method='post'><input type='text' name='user' placeholder='Your Name *' required='required' required><br><textarea class='form-text' name='new-reply' id='new-reply' placeholder='Your Reply' required='required'></textarea><input type='hidden' name='code' value='"+comCode+"' /><span style='float: right;'><a onclick='hideReplyForm();'>Cancel</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='submit' class='form-submit' id='form-reply' name='new_reply' value='Reply' /></span></form>");
    });
```

Here is the insertion code:

```
<?php
    // new comment
    if(isset($_POST['new_comment'])) {
        $new_com_name = $_SESSION['user'];
        $new_com_email = $_POST['email'];
        $new_com_website = $_POST['website'];
        $new_com_text = $_POST['comment'];
        $new_com_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $new_com_code = generateRandomString();
                
                // automatically inserts the ESCAPE CHARACTER - Now content will insert into database with single quote character
                $new_com_name = addslashes($new_com_name);
                $new_com_email = addslashes($new_com_email);
                $new_com_website = addslashes($new_com_website);
                $new_com_text = addslashes($new_com_text);
                
        if(isset($new_com_text)) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `parents` (`user`, `email`, `website`, `text`, `date`, `code`) VALUES ('$new_com_name', '$new_com_email', '$new_com_website', '$new_com_text', '$new_com_date', '$new_com_code')";
                        $result=$dbCon->query($sql);
                        
                        if ($result === TRUE) {
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Thank you for your comment! We will review it and hopefully approve it within 24 hours.');</script>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your comment has not been submitted.');</script>";
                        }
        }
        header("Location: ");
    }
    // new reply
    if(isset($_POST['new_reply'])) {
        $new_reply_name = $_SESSION['user'];
        $new_reply_email = $_POST['email'];
        $new_reply_website = $_POST['website'];
        $new_reply_text = $_POST['new-reply'];
        $new_reply_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $new_reply_code = $_POST['code'];
                
                // automatically inserts the ESCAPE CHARACTER - Now content will insert into database with single quote character
                $new_reply_name = addslashes($new_reply_name);
                $new_reply_email = addslashes($new_reply_email);
                $new_reply_website = addslashes($new_reply_website);
                $new_reply_text = addslashes($new_reply_text);
                
        if(isset($new_reply_text)) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `children` (`user`, `par_email`, `par_website`, `text`, `date`, `par_code`) VALUES ('$new_reply_name', '$new_reply_email', '$new_reply_website', '$new_reply_text', '$new_reply_date', '$new_reply_code')" or die(mysqli_error());
                        $resultReply=$dbCon->query($sql);
                        
                        if ($resultReply === TRUE) {
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Thank you for your reply! We will review it and hopefully approve it within 24 hours.');</script>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your reply has not been submitted.');</script>";
                        }
        }
        header("Location: ");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code. Show us how you do the insertion and how the parameters are passed to the function that does it.

Comment: I tried adding "var comEmail = $(this).attr("name");" and "var comWebsite = $(this).attr("name");" to the function to no avail. The values are inserted through an MySql query in a php file.

Comment: Please show us the php code that actually does the insertion and the piece of code that calls that function. We can't help you debug on information you've given us so far.